# Bootstrap Hypothesis Test: Comparing the Performance of two Models

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, bootstrap, model-comparison

I have two models $A$ and $B$ as well as a training set $X$. I want to test whether there is a significant difference in performance between model $A$ and $B$.

---

I'm attempting to do this via bootstrapping, i.e.

1. Draw a bootstrap sample $X*$
2. Train model $A$ and $B$ on $X*$ to get model $A*$ and $B*$
3. Obtain a single scalar performance estimate for $A*$ and $B*$ by
   testing on the out-of-bootstrap samples
4. Repeat this $B$ times

---

What is the correct way to compare the obtain performance distributions?

Comment: This would be one way od doing it, but why are you not using Cross Validation?

Comment: @user2974951 I was following the bootstrap method in chapter 7 of the [Elemtents of Statistical Learning](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/ESLII.pdf). How would I estimate significance using CV?

Answer (score 1):

What I think the authors are suggesting (I haven't checked) is to repeatedly train models A and B on bootstrap samples and then compare the two statistics using a test (for ex. proportion test if the statistic is between 0 and 1) and from the test draw a p-value. With a similar approach you could use say 5-fold CV to repeatedly train models A and B on random subsamples of the data and then compare the two statistics. The permutation test would be able to capture more variability in the data (I assume, usually why it's done) but it is going to be more computationally intensive.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however the authors suggest exactly what I described above as a procedure to estimate the performance mean and variance of a model. Intuitively, this allows for comparison via a significance test but this part is spared out in the book. Could you elaborate a bit more how you would use CV in that context? It seems to me that you would only obtain 5 performance values for both model A and B, which seems insufficient for estimating the performance distribution.

Comment: The procedure that I described is exactly what you presented, I only added the statistical test at the end (which is what I assumed they were doing, a proportion test). As I mentioned, you would do repeated 5-fold CV, so randomly partition the data into 5 folds, build the models on all folds, then repeat the process by further partitioning the data into 5 more random partitions, build the models, and so on...

Comment: I see, thanks. Initially I was using a Wilcox test to compare the two distributions, but I didn't find any literature justifying this approach. I'm not sure about the CV part though as (1) it seems more computationally intense, since at every iteration it need to build 5 models and (2) the obtained performance estimates from every CV are very correlated. For example, in the limit of k -> n, the variance of the CV estimates goes to zero.

Comment: There isn't much literature since this is rarely done. It's true that the CV approach is not great, permutations are better overall since they will have more variability. As for computational intensity, it depends how many resamples your perform.

Comment: What is instead the common approach to evaluate whether the performance of two models is *significantly* different with respect to some metric *p*?

Comment: There isn't one, you usually don't give p-values with machine learning performance estimates. If these were statistical models you could use an ANOVA and log likelihood estimates to derive a p-value, but even this is done only for a specific set of models.

Comment: How can you effectively make a comparison then? Every claims on superiority of a models performance over another seem inappropriate without knowing the significance of their performance difference.

Comment: This is not really the point of machine learning, with ML we usually ask what is the best overall model or what is a pretty and simple model. Any such comparisons are either purely objective (this model has +1 higher accuracy so it is better) or subjective (this model makes more sense to me).

Comment: That really doesn't make sense, because without knowing the significance of the higher performance one can not conclude that the model is objectively better, as it may just be better on that particular test set. What you are basically saying is that the point of machine learning is to be not scientific.

Comment: This is going off-topic so I won't be discussing this, I answered your question. And ML is an inexact science, there is no doubt about it, it's not about being unscientific.

Comment: Fair enough, I appreciate that you spend your time to give me some input.

Comment: @Scholar
To compare the accuracy (or other metric) of two models, first train them on the same dataset, then test both on a test set of size N. If model 1's accuracy is greater than model 2's, you might wonder if this difference is significant. The null hypothesis suggests both models perform similarly. To test this, at a 0.05 significance level, use a parametric statistical test if the data's distribution is known (as with accuracy). If not, bootstrap the difference to get a confidence interval and the p-value.